# line graph with multiple variables on y axis stepwise

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I need some help. Here is my data which i want to plot. I want to keep $path.ID on y axis and numerics of all other columns added stepwise. this is a subset of very large dataset so i want to pathID labels attached to each line. and also the values of the other columns with each point if possible.

```
head(table)
  Path.ID     sc    st    rc    rt
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 map00230     1    12     5    52
2 map00940     1    20    10    43
3 map01130    NA    15     8    34
4 map00983    NA    14     5    28
5 map00730    NA     5     3    26
6 map00982    NA    16     2    24
```

[somewhat like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhkNo.jpg)
Thank you

Comment: I wonder if this work for you with a label at the end of each line?
https://imgur.com/xqaz7KC

Comment: please send me the link to this code and i will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pseudo code.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# convert your table into a long format - sorry I am more used to this type of data
table_long <- table %>% gather(x_axis, value, sc:rt)

# Plot with ggplot2
ggplot() +
  # draw line
  geom_line(data=table_long, aes(x=x_axis, y=value, group=Path.ID, color=Path.ID)) +
  # draw label at the last x_axis in this case is **rt**
  geom_label(data=table_long %>% filter(x_axis=="rt"),
             aes(x=x_axis, y=value, label=Path.ID, fill=Path.ID),
             color="#FFFFFF")
```

*Note that with this code if a Path.ID doesn't have the rt value then it will not have any label*

Comment: > ggplot() +
+   # draw line
+   geom_line(data=table, aes(x=x_axis, y=value, group=Path.ID, color=Path.ID)) +
+   # draw label at the last x_axis in this case is **rt**
+   geom_label(data=table %>% filter(x_axis=="rt"),
+              aes(x=x_axis, y=value, label=Path.ID, fill=Path.ID),
+              color="#FFFFFF")
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @shahzad: I just recognized that I need to change the code of graph `table` to `table_long` instead.

Comment: I don't have actual data to say why it omitted rows. My guess is that many `Path.ID` have NA on `rt` column. If that is the case, you can review your data and try the `fill` option in `gather()` and fill with `0(Zero)` if that is acceptable.

Comment: i got it solved. thank you. but cex to reduce the text size of PathID is not working is there any other to do it

Comment: `geom_label()` has some options for size - you can check the options available and try it out which work best for you [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202836/discussion-between-sinh-nguyen-and-shahzad).

Answer (score 1):

```
p<-ggplot() +
  # draw line
  geom_line(data=table_long, aes(x=x_axis, y=value, group=Path.ID, color=Path.ID)) +
  geom_text(data=table_long %>% filter(x_axis=="rt"),
             aes(x=x_axis, y=value, label=Path.ID),
             color= "#050505", size = 3, check_overlap = TRUE)
p +labs(title= "title",x = "x-lable", y="y-label")
```

I had to use geom_text as i had large dataset and it gave me somewhat more clear graph
thank you @sinh it it helped a lot.